# Detect Lock Event without running app

Tags: xcode5

Is it possible to detect lock & unlock event when the app is not on running? I mean if i run the app it will display for me all lock & unlock time that done before running the app.

Thanks.

Comment: so basically you are looking for an already existing log of all lock & unlock events?

Answer (score 0):

Even with the app running, this is not possible. As a 3rd party developer for Apple, you do not have access to this sort of information from the device.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, It is possible to detect when the app in running by using "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete"

Comment: No that's not possible either. You're only way of knowing when the app starts in the didFinishLaucnh method in the app delegate and applicationWillTerminate to detect when it will end.